# How can I configure PHP 7.4 on Apache?

Tags: php, windows, apache, apache2.4, php-7.4

I am trying to configure PHP 7.4 and Apache 2.4 on my machine, but it is returning the following error:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 542 of C:/XIDServer/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: 
Can't locate API module structure 'php7_module' in file C:/XIDServer/php/php7.dll: No error
```

The bottom of my httpd.conf has the code:

```
# PHP7 module
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "C:/XIDServer/php/php7.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/XIDServer/php"
```

I've done already:

- Copy/paste php7.4 on the location: 'C:\XIDServer\php'
- Edited the php.ini file on 'C:\XIDServer\php\php.ini', enabling some modules:
- extension=curl
- extension=gd2
- extension=mbstring
- extension=mysql
- extension=pdo_mysql
- extension=xmlrpc
- Created the environment variable for php appointing to 'C:\XIDServer\php'
- Copy/paste Apache 2.4 64 bits to the folder: 'C:\XIDServer\Apache24'
- Edited the httpd.conf file, to appoint to the new location ('C:\XIDServer\Apache24')
- Installed the Windows Service of Apache 2.4
- Added the above lines on the bottom of file 'httpd.conf'

I'm doing it on a Windows Server 2012 machine.

Comment: What version of PHP? TS/NTS/x86/x64 ? Where from did you download your packages? https://www.apachelounge.com/download/ ?

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same issue.
You probably downloaded the Non-Thread-Save version of php7.
However you have to download the Thread-Save version.
Because in this version you will get a file called php7apache2_4.dll which you need to load as a module instead of php7.dll.

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/XIDServer/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

If you change this line it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the problem of missing the php7apache2_4.dll file in the 7.4.11 Non Thread Safe package for Windows. The solution was to choose a package named Thread Safe (Zip archive), which contains all the necessary files for manual installation and configuration. You can download it via the [link](https://windows.php.net/download)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download VC15 x64 Thread Safe version from this [link](https://windows.php.net/download)